# Implementing OAuth2/OIDC for VueJS SPA and asp.net core 3.1

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, single-page-application, openid-connect

- Vue front-end for `SPA` and `asp.net core 3.1` as backend for API
- Using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions` nuget package so, among others, SPA files will be served from a folder (wwwroot/dist) when users access .net core
- Back end API controller is decorated with `[Authorize]` attribute
- SPA router has authguards so protected routes are only available to authenticated users
- SPA will use `Axios` and pass a bearer token to the back end API

I want to implement `OAuth2`/`Oidc` authorization code with pkce using the `identityserver4` hosted on another system.

A request for the landing page should forward the user to identityserver4 for the login/password prompt and redirect back after completing all the steps with a token.

Ideally I want the .net core handle all the oauth/oidc steps and don't want to deal with it using `oidc-client` javascript client in SPA. Any suggestion on how I can accomplish this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well there are two standard models here and you need to choose one of them, depending on factors you care most about:

**OPTION 1: SPA SCENARIO**

- The SPA is the OAuth client and authenticates via Javascript tech
- The API is the OAuth resource server

It is not standard for a resource server to handle the authentication flow for a client - instead a client should authenticate, then call the resource server.

**OPTION 2: WEB BACK END SCENARIO**

People most commonly choose this option when they want to keep tokens out of the browser's Javascript code:

- A Web Back End in C# is the OAuth client
- The Web Back End needs to securely communicate with the browser and has to use an auth cookie for this
- To call an API the browser needs to either send the cookie to the web back end to get a token, or double hop all API calls via the web back end

**ABOUT OIDC CLIENT**

Personally I prefer option 1, which I think is closer to overall [SPA Goals](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/08/goal-1-requirements/), such as cross domain hosting and use of content delivery networks. OIDC Client can actually lead to a fairly simple SPA security implementation, as in this
[Client Side Implementation of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  I went with option 1.